# How do I split the "rating" field

Tags: python, sql, excel

so I'm looking at this dataset using Excel.

[image: dataset]

Is there anyway to split it so that :

I have the string "Funny", "Beautiful" as column names and the value of "count" for every row ?

I was able to split the column so that I have all the genres in the rows. But, they way I want is for the genres to be column names and the value of count in the rows.

Thanks.

Comment: a vba texttocolumns would do this. i'm surprised you didn't record yourself performing it on sample data and modify same to suit.

Comment: Please update this question with a small sample of the desired output.